# How to delete rows with recurring keyword?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of votes, and I need to limit each email's voting count to 3 per day by deleting the rows after their 3rd vote only for that same day. So I would just need to remove the fourth row for email "a". Thank you!

```
Date Email Idea
5/25 a     1
5/25 a     2
5/25 a     3
5/25 a     4
5/26 a     2
5/25 b     2
5/25 b     4
```

Comment: try df.groupby(['Date', 'Email']).head(3)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way: Do the cumulative sum by groups

```
df["Occ_Number"] = df.groupby(['Date','Email']).cumcount()+1
```

which gives:

```
 Date Email  Idea  Occ_Number
0  25-May     a     1           1
1  25-May     a     2           2
2  25-May     a     3           3
3  25-May     a     4           4
4  26-May     a     2           1
5  25-May     b     2           1
6  25-May     b     4           2
```

and create a new df that contains the rows that are max by group, but exclude those that occur only once

```
df_remove = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Date','Email'], sort=False)['Occ_Number'].max()).reset_index()
df_remove_2 = df_remove[df_remove['Occ_Number']>3]
```

This gives:

```
 Date Email  Occ_Number
0  25-May     a           4
```

Now, remove `df_remove_2` from your original df:

```
print (pd.merge(df,df_remove_2, indicator=True, how='outer')
         .query('_merge=="left_only"')
         .drop('_merge', axis=1))
```

which returns:

```
Date Email  Idea  Occ_Number
0  25-May     a     1           1
1  25-May     a     2           2
2  25-May     a     3           3
4  26-May     a     2           1
5  25-May     b     2           1
6  25-May     b     2           2
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your example. The following approach works.

```
d = {
    "Date": ["5/25", "5/25", "5/25", "5/25", "5/25", "5/25", "5/25"],
    "Email": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
    "Idea": [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.groupby(['Date', 'Email']).head(3)
```

```
    Date    Email   Idea
0   5/25    a       1
1   5/25    a       2
2   5/25    a       3
4   5/25    b       2
5   5/25    b       2
6   5/25    b       4
```

Which looks like the wanted behavior.